# have event listener effect multiple items in a stack

Tags: javascript, mouseover, element, stacked

I am trying to figure out how to have an event listner change the class for multiple items that are stacked on top of each other.

I have a current fiddle here that I am working on, basically when someone clicks the button and hovers an object it changes the class of the object that is hovered.  I would like to take this a step further so that when two object are positioned on top of eachother that both objects will be effected.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Currently when you click and hover it only effects the top-most element. I would like to effect both the top and bottom element.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

http://jsfiddle.net/Ltdgx363/1/

```
obj=document.getElementsByTagName("object");
var mouseDown = 0;
document.onmousedown = function() { 
++mouseDown;
}
document.onmouseup = function() {
  --mouseDown;
}
for(i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
obj[i].addEventListener("mouseover", colorred ,false);
}
function colorred(){
if(mouseDown>0){
    this.className = "red";
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not shure what you mean. Stacked can mean a lot of things, if you are using elements without absolute/fixed/relative position, all elements are rendered beneath one another, in the order they appear in your html. 

You could also mean that the elements have a different z-index, in which case, they are on top of each other, the answer would be very different.

Comment: here is the game I am building functionality for:  http://ZombiePrepKit.com

Comment: @nate, i've updated your jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Ltdgx363/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understood your question correct, you can do that with jQuery `parent()` and `children()`. See my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yu404vf2/2/

Your function basically becomes like:

```
function colorred(){
    if(mouseDown>0){
        this.className = "red";
    }
    $(this).parents().class = "red";
}
```

This works if objects are stacked like:

```
<object id="object3">Test3
 <object id="object4">Test4</object>
</object>
```

But not if objects are stacked due to `z-index`/ position absolute.

If you need the objects below the mouse pointer there is a nice function in javascrtipt called `elementFromPoint` which you can use like:

```
var x = event.clientX, y = event.clientY,
elementMouseIsOver = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
elementMouseIsOver.class="red";
```

Updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yu404vf2/5/

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid jquery and also I can't stack the objects inside eachother.  If its just not possible its not absolutely necessary for my functionality but it would be nice to be able to do this.  Currently the objects are next to eachother.  you can see a live demo of the game I am programming here: http://ZombiePrepKit.com

Comment: I figured it out, check my answer you will love it.

Comment: awesome, that is exactly what I'm looking for!  now do you have any advice on making it mobile friendly so it works with a swipe?

Comment: That is another question :) feel free to post it as question. I do not know the answer right now. If my answer worked for you, mark it as accepted so it can also help other people with the same problem. Thanks!

Comment: Actually you need to use touchevent on top of the mouse event listener. See here http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/touchevents.shtml

Comment: I'm working on the concept for the mobile application - here is what I have so far:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32850128/creating-a-mouse-and-swipe-event-for-mobile-applications

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of doing this, but assuming you don't want to use a library. I have updated your jsfiddle, but added the comments here.

```
//find all objects, and create an empty array, to contain the object id's later on.
var r_objects = document.getElementsByTagName('object');
var r_ids = [];

/*
your colorred function, 
not using your general mousedown tracker, 
but added the mousedown eventListener to your objects.
*/

var colorred = function(obj,addClass){
     /* 
     find the index of your currently clicked element, 
     to determine if there are any "underneath" it, objects 
     that are rendered earlier, get a lower index. 
     */
     oIndex = r_ids.indexOf(obj.id); 

     /* 
     loop through the indexes lower and the same as the element 
     your mouse is on. you can determine the depth here, by not looping
     through, but by simply subtracting or adding to the oIndex var, and 
     using it as a key in your r_objects array. addClass is true or false,
     depending on the event, so it also removes the class after your 
     mouseup event is triggered 
     */

     for(i = 0; i <= oIndex; i++){
        affectedObj = r_objects[i];
        if(addClass){
            affectedObj.className = "red";
        }else{
            affectedObj.className = "";
        }
    };
};

var addListeners = function(){
    for(i = 0; i < r_objects.length; i++){
        obj = r_objects[i];
        obj.addEventListener('mousedown',function(){
            colorred(this,true);
        });
        obj.addEventListener('mouseup',function(){
            colorred(this,false);
        });

        //add the id to the r_ids array 
        r_ids.push(obj.id);
    };
};
addListeners();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ltdgx363/3/

You can determine the "depth" of the affected elements, by playing around with the for loop.